# Register a custom conversion service while retaining the defaults?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In a spring-mvc 3.2.RELEASE project I'd like to use org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter to easily get me entities injected.

It works fine when using this config:

```
<beans:bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean" />

<beans:bean id="conversionService"
    class="org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService" /> 

<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="conversionService" />
</beans:bean>

<annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />
```

But then Spring isn't loading the formatter for dealing with Joda time types and i get "Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type org.joda.time.LocalDate for property"

Using only

```
<annotation-driven/>
```

The Joda conversion works but not the entity injection.

How do you wire it upp so both work?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what you were doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this answers the question, but I came across a similar problem and this is how I resolved it.

I had implemented a custom converter and conversion service using the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html)

```
<bean id="conversionService"
  class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            <bean class="example.MyCustomConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The result was what @NA described - this loses the default joda time support and the following definition in an unrelated controller no longer works

```
@PathVariable(value="day") @DateTimeFormat(pattern=DATE_FORMAT) LocalDate date
```

The solutions was instead of using `org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean`, I began using `org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean`.

Comment: This works just fine, I get from the documentation that FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean takes the list provided and adds them to the defaults but ConversionServiceFactoryBean just replaces the list completely.